# r - grepl vs matches

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I am experiencing a little problem using the `matches` function from `dplyr` package.

From this dataset, I would like to extract the column names starting with `enj`

```
    enj1 enj2 Enjm
bbc    1    1    2
bca    1    1    2
```

With `grepl`, I can do this

```
dt[, grepl('enj', colnames(dt))]
```

and get

```
    enj1 enj2
bbc    1    1
bca    1    1
```

However the function `matches` does **not** give me the correct answer

```
library(dplyr) 

dt %>% select(matches('enj') )
# or 
dt %>% select(matches('^enj') )
```

Any idea why ?

```
dt = structure(list(enj1 = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Names = c("bbc", 
"bca"), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), enj2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L), .Names = c("bbc", "bca"), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    Enjm = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Names = c("bbc", "bca"), .Label = "2", class = "factor")), .Names = c("enj1", 
"enj2", "Enjm"), row.names = c("bbc", "bca"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @docendodiscimus No, you're wrong. It's not a function at all. If it were a it would've been in the package namespace, which it's not and was the basis of my comment. I was able to answer this question successfully by realizing there's no `matches` function in `dplyr`. It turns out he was talking about an argument to `select` that's passed to the `base` function `match`.

Comment: @Hack-R, as documented in [dplyr's github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/select-utils.R) (lines 88-92) you can see that it is indeed a helper function from `dplyr`. The reason it's not in the namespace is because it's not an exported function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you didn't set `ignore.case = F`.

```
> dt %>% select(matches('^enj',  ignore.case = F) )
    enj1 enj2
bbc    1    1
bca    1    1
>
```

Comment: thank for your answer. Where did you find the doc ? the function has none. thanks

Comment: @giacomoV `matches` isn't a function, it's an argument to the `select` function. This is why I got a little confused at first when you referred to it as a function in the question. The function is `select` and `select` calls the base `match` function in a wrapper based on the `matches` argument. You can get its man page with `?select`.

Comment: @Hack-R, the function `base::match` is not related to `matches` in any way. You can see that `dplyr:::matches` is defined with three arguments and one of them is called `match` but it could be called anything else.